# How can I prevent password requests whenever I try to access a secondary drive?

Tags: permissions, mount, password

I am a long-time computer professional, now retired. I am, however, a newbie to Ubuntu/Linux.

I built a new system using Ubuntu 20.04 as the main OS, the system includes 2 additional SSDs and 4 HDs from the prior (dead) system. The prior system was multi-boot with Windows 7>10 and OS/2. The file systems on the older drives are a mix of NTFS, JFS, and FAT32, although I don't think this really matters.
When I try to mount any of the partitions on one of the other drives via Files > Other Locations, I am required to enter my password, twice for the first request, and sometimes again for a different drive.
This is *MY* computer. I am the only person living in the house, and NO ONE ELSE has access to the machine. I would like to prevent the constant requests for my password every time I try to do something.

Any suggestions?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. Run the Disks program
2. Select the appropriate disk form the left hand pane.
3. Click the Additional Partition Options icon.
4. Edit Mount Options.
5. Set User Session Defaults to Off.
6. Check the Mount At Startup box.
7. Check the Show In User Interface box.
8. OK.
9. Repeat for the other hard disks.
10. Reboot.
    You should find your additional disks are now mounted permanently.

Comment: Several drives have worked. Several others have the Mount Options all greyed out.  Any idea why?